# Why can't I change the list I'm iterating from when using yield

Tags: python

I have some reproducible code here:

```
def test():
    a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    for _ in range(len(a)):
        a.append(a.pop(0)) 
        for i in range(2,4):
            print(a)
            yield(i, a)
```

This prints out:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[2, 3, 0, 1]
[2, 3, 0, 1]
[3, 0, 1, 2]
[3, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Which is what I expected, but when I do `list(test())` I get:

```
[(2, [0, 1, 2, 3]),
 (3, [0, 1, 2, 3]),
 (2, [0, 1, 2, 3]),
 (3, [0, 1, 2, 3]),
 (2, [0, 1, 2, 3]),
 (3, [0, 1, 2, 3]),
 (2, [0, 1, 2, 3]),
 (3, [0, 1, 2, 3])]
```

Why is this the case, and what can I do to work around it?

Comment: Because you always return a *reference* to the list, not a *copy* of the list.

Comment: You print only "a", but return (i, a).

Comment: @AndreyLukyanenko: I think the OP is confused about the *content* of the list: the fact that all the yields have the same list.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem ah, I see now. Then your answer is correct.

Comment: @AndreyLukyanenko yes sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you always return `(i,a)` now `a` is a *reference* to the list. So you constantly return a *reference* to the *same* list. This is no problem for the `print` statement, since it immediately prints the state of `a` *at that moment*.

You can return a *copy* of the list, for instance like:

```
def test():
    a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    for _ in range(len(a)):
        a.append(a.pop(0)) 
        for i in range(2,4):
            print(a)
            yield(i, list(a))
```

Answer (score 3):

You're yielding the same list every time, so the caller's list simply has a bunch of references to that list, which has been updated each time they called. You need to make copies of the list when you yield:

```
def test():
    a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    for _ in range(len(a)):
        a.append(a.pop(0)) 
        for i in range(2,4):
            print(a)
            yield(i, a[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicit better implicit:

```
import copy
def test():
    a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    for _ in range(len(a)):
        a.append(a.pop(0)) 
        for i in range(2,4):
            print(a)
            yield(i, copy.copy(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

You end up with a list of tuples, and the second element of the tuple is *the same list*. You might notice that they are all equivalent to the last list the generator makes, not the first; the list is changing, but the tuples all have references to the same one.

To make this clear, try to modify one of the lists. For example, if you run `l[0][1].append(4)`, you will get

```
[(2, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 (3, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 (2, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 (3, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 (2, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 (3, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 (2, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 (3, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]
```

All of the lists had 4 appended, because there is only one list.

If you want to return a copy, there are several ways. You could `yield (i, a[:])` (using slice notation to get a copy), `yield (i, list(a))` (using the `list` constructor to get a copy), or `yield (i, copy.copy(a))` (using the `copy` module).